# java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException with jlink created runtime

Tags: zip, nio, jlink

I am working on adopting `jlink` in order to create a much smaller runtime to embed with the macOS application version of a free software package, and I nearly have it working (with my application shrinking from around 260MB to 90MB). The problem that I am running into is that my software uses the ZIP filesystem, and when it tries to open such a filesystem when running with the `jlink`-created runtime, code that works fine with the normal OpenJDK 11 runtime suddenly crashes with:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem                  
java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider not found
```

I am assuming this is because jlink has no way of knowing without being told that ZIP filesystem support should be included in my runtime, since my code doesn’t explicitly mention any of its classes (they are used indirectly via `java.nio`).

So does anyone know how I can explicitly tell `jlink` to include them?

Comment: The jlink `--suggest-providers` option may be useful here. More specifically `--suggest-providers java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider` at the end of your jlink command will find the modules that provide this service. In this case it will tell you that `jdk.zipfs` is the service provider module you want.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, shortly after posting this question, my google-fu improved, and I found the answer. In JDK 11, [`jdk.zipfs`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html) is its own module, containing this provider. So I just needed to add that to my `--add-modules` list, and it is now working.